# Delete YouTube channel in order to unlink G+ from YouTube

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I want to get my old YouTube username back and completely abandon the nightmare that carries the name Google+. In order to do so, I need to delete my G+ channel, and in order to do that, I need to delete my YouTube channel.

I have a lot of playlists and favorites on my YouTube and I don't want to lose them. If I read correctly, with deleting your new YouTube channel you will also delete all information from the site, that you have posted since the creation of the channel.

According to the YouTube channel delete confirmation page it will delete 0 videos, 1 abbo, and 23 reactions from my account.

However, it does not list if it will delete any playlists or favorites from my account.

Does anyone know for sure, if you delete your YouTube channel, **will the playlists that existed before creating that channel** also be removed?

Comment: Plz mark as correct if it worked

Comment: Sorry I wouldn't know if your answer worked because it was posted too late for me to try. I had deleted everything back then.

Comment: i see. Good luck!

Comment: No. You can undelete (or reopen Google+) and your YouTube install there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question.. well I've found this out the hard way. The answer is yes, if you try to delete your Google+ page then all information on your Youtube account is lost as well.

Please do NOT follow in my footsteps and leave all your settings as they are, unless you really want to delete your Youtube account :)

Comment: No. You can undelete (or reopen Google+) and your YouTube install there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete anything!

What you need to do is:

1. Create a new Gmail account, and a new G+ page with you old account.
2. Add the new account as admin of the page (you'll need to wait some time after creating it before being able to do that), then transfer the channel from your account to the page (Google how before trying!), then transfer it from the page to the new account.

I've done this.